# Generating excel file of extension .xlsx

Tags: excel, xlsx, xls

Using this :

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentLength(byteArray.length);
headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"));
headers.setCacheControl(CacheControl.noCache());
headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=yourFileName.xlsx");
```

When the file gets generated then it shows as `*.xls`.
Ideally file should get generated as `*.xlsx`, but file name extension is `*.xls`.

Tried this:

```
headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"));
```

But no luck.